# C# Windows CE 3.0 P/Invoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, windows-ce

So a while ago I was trying a code snippet that measures the length of a string block. I created a function out of that code snippet and tested it on a Windows Forms application.

The function is originally meant for a Windows Device application. I transferred the function to the devapp and to my surprise one of the methods does not exist on the program's context.

The code is

```
TextRenderer.MeasureText(string Text, font Font)
```

Will the method work by calling the dll with P/Invoke?
If so what is the signature of TextRenderer.MeasureText?

Comment: First of all, don't you already kinda have the signature of MeasureText, as you are USING IT? Anyways, see if you can use Graphics.From...().MeasureString(...)

Comment: @YoryeNathan Yes it does, in the winform application, but not in the device application. I already declared the System.Windows.Forms namespace in my devapp but TextRenderer does not appear.

Comment: I suggested trying the MeasureString method of Graphics.

Comment: Tried that method, but the return values are inconsistent.

Comment: What are you going to p/invoke to? This is a .net framework method.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I tried measuring different blocks of string with same width measuring 393px. The MeasureText method returned the same values for all the string blocks, but MeasureString returned different values.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I only assumed that the method can be called through P/Invoke. Is there a way to make the .Net Framework method work on a C# DevApp? I really need this MeasureText to work on my application because this is the only method that returns the exact values I needed.

Comment: The values are consistent for the same fonts in the same sizes, for the same strings.